# Toggle buttons on or off based on variable value

Tags: php, css

I am trying to create some dynamic info on our company store "more info" pages.  I have a basic template set up, but am having a bit of difficulty getting some of the functionality and visibility of items to toggle on or off.

Basically, there are some items that come in different colors, but they vary from one product to the next.  I have set up in our database the options for each color, and have assigned the color's hex code to a variable in php.  This part is working fine.  The issue I am running into is, some items have more color options than the other.  I would like to set it up to use the same template for each product without having to go in and edit each product page individually (if possible).  So, I want to set up something that will toggle the color buttons hidden if the value is "NULL," and visible if the value has anything BUT "NULL" in it.

Here is the code I have set up, but it is not reading the 'else' statement, regardless of what the variable contains.

```
<div class="tooltip">
<span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $Color11; ?></span>
<?php
if($Hex11=="NULL") {
    '<button class ="button button11" style="display:none"></button>';
}
else {
    '<button type="button" class="button button11"></button>';
}
?></div>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add echo to your code.

```
<div class="tooltip">
<span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $Color11; ?></span>
<?php
if($Hex11=="NULL") {
echo '<button class ="button button11" style="display:none"></button>';
} else {
echo '<button type="button" class="button button11"></button>';
}
?></div>
```

Comment: Adding echo makes all values ignore the "NULL" values, and ends up showing all buttons, regardless of the value of their assigned variable.  Basically the opposite of what it was doing prior to adding echo.

Comment: take the quotes away from null instead of "null" which is a string because of the quotes use just $Hex11 == NULL

Comment: Null isnt supposed to be a string

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!

Comment: One other thing...I have an onClick event attached to the visible buttons which essentially change the image to the new color.  When I added it to the code after fixing the visibility, and reuploaded, I get an "500 internal server error."    else {
 echo '<button type="button" class="button button1" onClick='document.getElementById("Demo").src = "echo $image1;"'></button>';
 }  This is the code as I have it now.

Comment: what  is  demo can you post it?

Comment: It's more or less just an "id." <img id="Demo" src="<?php echo $default; ?>" width="400" align="left">.  This was working prior to adding the php info from the database, so not sure if its even possible now to make it work the same way.

Comment: try this document.getElementById("Demo").src = "<?php echo $image1; ?>"

Comment: you need to create a function and place it in the onclick really.  Post another question with it so i can work it out

Comment: I have tried that, but because this is inside my current <?php ?> code that I posted originally, I get an error.  I am guessing because of calling the php tag inside a php tag?  I tried removing the tag after .src=, but I still get an error.

Comment: I will try the function.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `if-else`, you can just use `if`:

```
if(isset($Hex11) && !empty($Hex11)) {
    echo '<button type="button" class="button button11"></button>';
}
```

And secondly, I believe, its NULL and not "NULL". If you are fetching it from database, you can easily make changes for the NULL by addition a `where` clause for it.